# How to present viewController from tabBar, like instagram post item in tabBar [Swift]

Tags: swift, instagram, tabbar

In my iOS app I've a tabBarController and I want to use one of this buttons to PRESENT a viewController, like for instagram "+" item (when you want to add new posts).
Now I've tried with the following code, but when I dismiss viewController, it go to + page, and I don't want this.
I don't know if I explained myself well, but it works like the button on the instagram tabBar.

class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tabBar.tintColor = .white

    window = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
           .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
           .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
           .compactMap({$0})
           .first?.windows
           .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
}

func presentView() {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "CreateComment", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "NAV_CONTROLLER")

    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

    // I tried to use window because I want to present this viewController over all other viewControllers.
    window?.rootViewController = self // tabBarController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    guard let items = tabBar.items else { return }

    switch item {
    case items.first: break
    case items.second: presentView()
    case items.last: break

    default: break
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify by what you want the button to do? It sounds like from your explanation that a viewcontroller is presented properly when user touches the button. Also, what do you mean by dismissing the viewcontroller takes you to "+page" (what is +page)?

Comment: Do you know instagram + button to add new posts? I want a button like this.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am also looking for something similar for an app I am building.